# Xamarin Android Player Showing 0 Downloadable devices?

Tags: android, xamarin

ive downloaded and installed everything what need to be,

but when i ran the xamarin android player , i showing downloadable devices (0)"

i tried changing my i.p. , its not working

what should i do

i searched google and found this link 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27971/set-proxy-to-download-devices-in-xamarin-android-player

but i don't know how they solved the problem

Comment: Try turning off the firewall, restart your PC, and close all unecessary applications. try Booting into safe mode with networking enabled and see if the problem persists. Otherwise try reinstalling

Comment: Same here, very frustrating. Any news?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SDKs installed?

If you go into your Android SDK Manager, make sure at least one of the APIs is installed with some system images and the SDK Platform.

It may not be able to find devices to download that match installed SDKs on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows 10. Solved it by searching Network proxy settings then under use a proxy server put it on and fill your proxy address and port then click save. Hope it helps someone.